# Undefined property while trying to connect to a laravel powered database

Tags: php, laravel

I tried to create middleware to control the access of users, why I created a table roles may I have this error

> Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$role_name

User model

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
class User extends Authenticatable
{

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
    public function roles(){
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Role','role_id','id');
    }

    public function  hasRole($title){
        $user_role=$this->with('roles');
        if(!is_null($user_role)){
            $user_role=$user_role->role_name;
        }
        return ($user_role==$title)?true:false;
    }
}
```

the middleware create

```
 <?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class create
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next,$Admin,$SuperAdmin)
    {
        $User=$request->user();

        return ($User->hasRole($SuperAdmin)||$User->hasRole($Admin))?$next($request):response(view('errors.401'),401);
    }
}
```

Comment: share the middleware code please

Comment: The error relates to the fact you haven't yet executed the query you are calling `role_name` on and so you are trying to call that on a Query Builder object not a result object. I'm not 100% on this, but try `$user_role=$this->with('roles')->get();`

Answer (score 0):

What you what to do is to receive the relation object. You can do it in this way:

```
public function  hasRole($title){
    $user_role = '';
    if(!is_null($this->roles)){
        $user_role=$this->roles->role_name;
    }
    return ($user_role==$title)?true:false;
}
```

The `with(...)` statment is useful for receiving relation when you're working on collection of elements (eager load constraint).